# How to change each textbox value based on onchange each selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are many divs that named record .in these divs I have a select box that changes the value and attribute of the textboxes. the code works well. but the problem is when a select box change, all of the textbox values will be change. how to change a value of textboxes base on each select box. not all of them?
here are my codes:

```js
 

$(function () {
    $('select[name=type]').change(function () {
        var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
        $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
        $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
        $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
    });
});
```

```css
  .to_validate:invalid {
    color: navy;
    outline: none; 
    border-color: #ff1050;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
.record {
    width:50%; 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
  

<html>
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="record">
                <select name="type" class="minimal">
                    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
                    <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
                    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="record">
                <select name="type" class="minimal">
                    <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
                    <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
                    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('select[name=type]').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
    $(this).siblings('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
    $(this).siblings('input[name=hostInput]').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
    $(this).siblings('input[name=hostInput]').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
.record {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="record">
      <select name="type" class="minimal">
        <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
        <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
        <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX</option>
      </select>

      <br/>

      <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host" />

    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="record">
      <select name="type" class="minimal">
        <option value="Record" selected hidden>Record</option>
        <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
        <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX</option>
      </select>

      <br/>

      <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" title="Wrong host" />

    </div>


    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Use `this` context with [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

1. Using `this` context will get you the current select.
2. Using `siblings()` will get you the siblings of the current select then giving parameter `input[name=hostInput]` will get the exact input

Comment: Give some explanation about your answer. It will help others also.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write the JavaScript part like this. With jQuery you can chain commands, it is exactly the same answer though but might be easier to read. Furthermore, you can use .data('nameOfAttr') for data-name-of-attr values in html (see http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Generally I don't use 'siblings' since this doesn't always work (depends heavily on your html structure). When you work in a team where other people can edit your code as well you can also look for the `closest('.record')` and find in that scope your input. This way your code will work whenever it is a sibling or not, eg. if the select is wrapped in a div or span (this is something common when you customise your selectbox).

Performance tip: Ideally you don't use [name=*nameHere*] selectors because this type of selector is quite slow compared to id and className selectors (`#id` or `.js_some_class_name`). But this code is not part of a bigger JavaScript application (by the looks of it), so you are fine if you use this selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select[name=type]').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");

    $(this).closest('.record').find('input[name=hostInput]')
        .attr('pattern', $option.data('pattern'))
        .attr('placeholder', $option.data('placeholder'))
        .attr('title', $option.data('title'));
  });
});
```